# German student visa is issued for only 2 months: why? and is it a common practice?

Tags: visa, germany, student-visa

I have made a student-visa application to one of the German embassies several weeks ago, and today, I got my visa. In my application, I have stated that my studies will last at least 2 years, but they issued a D-type visa valid for only 2 months.

I was expecting them to issue the visa for 3 months. Is this a common practice? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not common practice.

Generaly a 3 months D-Visa is issued (see **6.4.2.1**) in cases when issued with the goal of recieving a residence permit.

Exceptions can, however, be made (see **6.4.2.2**).

In your case, since a semester generally starts in September, they probably want you to complete the process before the semester begins.

Most appointments must be made online, for which you probably  must create an account. The waiting time for appointments is often long, so doing this as early as possible is advised.

Should the given appointment be **after** the visa expires, then the visa will automatically be extended. The print out of the appointment serves as proof.

---

**Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift zum Aufenthaltsgesetz**
(General administrative regulation on the Residence Act)
Vom 26. Oktober 2009

> **6.4.2.1**
> Nationale Visa werden, **sofern nicht besondere Umstände eine Abweichung rechtfertigen, etwa um eine frühzeitige Vorsprache bei der Ausländerbehörde zu bewirken**, für drei Monate ausgestellt. Da das „D“-Visum nur zur Durchreise durch das Hoheitsgebiet der anderen Mitgliedstaaten und nicht zum Aufenthalt im Schengenraum berechtigt, sollten nationale Visa grundsätzlich als „D+C“ mit mehrfacher Einreise und grundsätzlich nur für drei Monate erteilt werden. Für Folgeaufenthalte ist bei Erfüllung der Voraussetzungen eine Aufenthaltserlaubnis zu erteilen.
>
> > National visas are issued for three months, **unless special circumstances justify a deviation, for example to arrange an early appointment with the immigration office**.  Since the "D" visa only allows you to travel through the territory of the other Member States and not to stay in the Schengen area, national visas should generally be issued as "D + C" with multiple entries and generally only for three months.  A residence permit must be issued for subsequent stays if the requirements are met.
>
> **6.4.2.2**
> In Absprache mit der zuständigen Ausländerbehörde können im Einzelfall zur Wahrung von Sicherheitsbelangen eine kürzere Geltungsdauer vorgesehen und Nebenbestimmungen verfügt werden (z. B. **Verpflichtung zur sofortigen Vorsprache bei der Ausländerbehörde nach der Einreise**, Beschränkung auf einen bestimmten Studienort und Studiengang), wobei entsprechende Anregungen bereits bei Übersendung des Visumantrags in das Votum an die Ausländerbehörde aufgenommen werden können.
>
> > In consultation with the responsible immigration authority, a shorter period of validity can be provided in individual cases to safeguard security issues and ancillary provisions can be enacted (e.g. **obligation to speak to the immigration authority immediately after entry**, restriction to a specific place of study and degree program), with corresponding suggestions already  can be included in the vote when sending the visa application to the immigration office.

---

**Sources**:

- [Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift zum Aufenthaltsgesetz](http://www.verwaltungsvorschriften-im-internet.de/bsvwvbund_26102009_MI31284060.htm)

  - [Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift zum Aufenthaltsgesetz vom 26. Oktober 2009](http://www.verwaltungsvorschriften-im-internet.de/pdf/BMI-MI3-20091026-SF-A001.pdf) (pdf)