# Working remotely with Schengen visa - is it possible?

Tags: schengen, norway

I'm going to visit Schengen area, Norway. Can I work remotely for my company back in India from there? Are there any restrictions on that?

Answer (score 2):

The Schengen visa in and of itself doesn't give you any permission to *work* and there are indeed restrictions on that. If you were to come to the Schengen area to work for a brief period of time, you would need permission (implicit or explicit) on top of your Schengen visa. And if you were to apply for a Schengen visa specifically to come and work in the area, you would need to submit evidence that you do have the right to carry out this work with your application. Of course, those rules were defined with onsite work in mind but there is no blanket exception for remote work. That part is easy and unambiguous.

To muddy the waters somewhat, some work activities (checking emails, attending the odd online meeting) might be considered “business”. It's also likely remote work is not a focus for enforcement or perhaps even falls under some local exemption. It remains the case that, in general, (remote) work is not allowed under the Schengen regime.

Answer (score -2):

No, a **C-Visa** ('short stay visa', 'Schengen Visa')  does not generally allow any 3rd country nationals to work during their stay.

---

For 3rd country nationals, permission to work is *solely* within the **competence** of each individual member state.

For this a **D-Visa** ('long-stay visa', 'National Visa'), must be issued under which a member state can determine under what conditions a 3rd country national may stay (and do) **within their territory**.

One member state **cannot** grant permission for a 3rd country national to work in another member state.

Outside their territory, the D-Visa will be treated as a C-Visa within the Schengen Area. This also applies to a **residence permit** issued by a Schengen member state.

Comment: The distinction between Schengen visas and national ("D") visas is based on the length of stay, not the purpose. Your answer muddles the two and that's not particularly helpful.

Comment: @Relaxed Here you are wrong. The difference is the purpose and not the length. A D-Visa can also (and for students often are before semester begin) be issued for a 30 day period.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if some countries did it, it's not worth fighting over for the Commission (which has essentially given up enforcing the Schengen regulations) but that's simply not the case. That's plain to see in the text of the regulations, the various handbooks, etc. Countries that do apply them correctly certainly do not issue D-visas in these situations.

Comment: Consider for example, article 1(1) of the Schengen visa code: "This Regulation establishes the procedures and conditions for issuing visas for intended stays on the territory of the Member States not exceeding 90 days in any 180-day period." No mention of purpose, clear duration limit and if countries could simply have a parallel system of short-term visas that would be a massive loophole and defeat the whole purpose of the regulation.

Comment: I could go on as this is evident in many small details of the text but the clearest evidence is that what you insist on calling "D-visa" is in fact only referred to as a “national **long-stay** visa" in this regulation and the rest of EU law.

Comment: @Relaxed Oh, please go on with Annex VII (Filling in the visa sticker) of the Visa Code: *In order to facilitate matters for the control authorities, this heading specifies the **type of visa** using the letters A, C and **D**...*. This is how the border control (and I assume the Airlines) know which type of visa the traveler has.

Comment: Skillful way to deflect without addressing any of the substantial points I made, well done. Of course, I know the code exists but the fact is that what this code represents is actually called a “national long-stay visa”. Repeatedly, all over the regulation and elsewhere. Are you denying that? Never encountered the phrase? How does the annex negate all the contents of the regulation? Are you confused about the meaning of “long-stay”? Or what?

Comment: For it's obviously right there, in the annex you chose to bring up, "D: long-stay visa". What kind of point is that?

Comment: @Relaxed That was solely a rearion to your 'what you insist on calling "D-visa"' comment. The fact if the matter is that they are visas issued based on national laws, not all of which is to take up residence. For Germany **Working-Holiday-Visa** (§ 19c Abs 1 AufenthG) is one of these cases. The purpose, a § number, will be added in the remarks portion of the visa sticker which have the type D.

Comment: @Relaxed The point is, that all visa holder needs to do is look at the visa sticker the see what type of visa they have. During the first lockdown, those that had a **D** were allowed in, those with a **C** were not.

Comment: I never mentioned residence or suggested people shouldn't care about the kind of visa they have, I just reminded you that the distinction between a Schengen visa (marked with a C on the sticker) and a national long-stay visa (marked with a D) is the length of stay (longer or shorter than 90 days), not the purpose. Are we in agreement with that? Do you realize your initial comment was wrong? Will you edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: @Relaxed No, because a D-Visa can be issued for less than 3 months and for other purposes outside the commonly agreed Schengen visa policy. [germany - German student visa is issued for only 2 months: why? and is it a common practice? - Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/20800/17166)

Comment: I already discussed that 4 hours ago. That Germany disregards EU law doesn't change the meaning of the regulation. What basis do you have to claim the purpose is the main factor when duration of stay is the only one mentioned explicitly? What do you make of the fact that the only non-Schengen visas envisioned by the regulation are “national **long-stay** visas” and states explicitly that this is the meaning of the “D" code on the sticker?